# ¿Porque no ejecuta el controlador LoginController.php en la autorización de rol de usuarios Middleware?

Tags: laravel, login, autenticación, agrupación

Tengo implementado la autenticación de usuarios en laravel usando Middleware; que proporciona un mecanismo conveniente para filtrar las solicitudes HTTP que ingresan a su aplicación. Para la implementación de los Middleware use el comando php artisan make:middleware ; para mi proyecto se tiene 3 roles que son Administrador, Vendedor y Comprador (cuando se creó cada usuario se le asigno un rol que va a tener); como se dice se va a crear 3 middleware en mi proyecto laravel
php artisan make:middleware Administrador
php artisan make:middleware Vendedor
php artisan make:middleware Comprador

Estos middleware crean en la ruta \app\Http\Middleware\ (Administrador, Vendedor, Comprador); una vez que he creado los 3 respectivos middleware en el archivo kernel.php del proyectolaravel se definio las rutas de los middleware en el método $routeMiddleware; asi de la siguiente manera:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'Administrador' => \App\Http\Middleware\Administrador::class,
        'Vendedor' => \App\Http\Middleware\Vendedor::class,
        'Comprador' => \App\Http\Middleware\Comprador::class,
        
    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}
```

En el archivo web.php que esta en la ruta \routes\web.php se ha agrupado las rutas por grupos de middleware de acuerdo al rol Administrador, Vendedor, Comprador que asi queda el archivo web.php

```html
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {
     
    Route::get('/','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');

});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
      
    Route::get('/main', function () {
        return view('contenido/contenido');
    })->name('main');

    Route::get('/','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['Comprador']], function () {

                
        Route::get('/categoria', 'CategoriaController@index');
        Route::post('/categoria/registrar', 'CategoriaController@store');
        Route::put('/categoria/actualizar', 'CategoriaController@update');
        Route::put('/categoria/desactivar', 'CategoriaController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/categoria/activar', 'CategoriaController@activar');
        Route::get('/categoria/selectCategoria', 'CategoriaController@selectCategoria');
        
        Route::get('/producto', 'ProductoController@index');
        Route::post('/producto/registrar', 'ProductoController@store');
        Route::put('/producto/actualizar', 'ProductoController@update');
        Route::put('/producto/desactivar', 'ProductoController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/producto/activar', 'ProductoController@activar');
        
        Route::get('/proveedor', 'ProveedorController@index');
        Route::post('/proveedor/registrar', 'ProveedorController@store');
        Route::put('/proveedor/actualizar', 'ProveedorController@update');
        
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['Vendedor']], function () {

        Route::get('/categoria', 'CategoriaController@index');
        Route::post('/categoria/registrar', 'CategoriaController@store');
        Route::put('/categoria/actualizar', 'CategoriaController@update');
        Route::put('/categoria/desactivar', 'CategoriaController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/categoria/activar', 'CategoriaController@activar');
        Route::get('/categoria/selectCategoria', 'CategoriaController@selectCategoria');
        
        Route::get('/producto', 'ProductoController@index');
        Route::post('/producto/registrar', 'ProductoController@store');
        Route::put('/producto/actualizar', 'ProductoController@update');
        Route::put('/producto/desactivar', 'ProductoController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/producto/activar', 'ProductoController@activar');
        
        Route::get('/cliente', 'ClienteController@index');
        Route::post('/cliente/registrar', 'ClienteController@store');
        Route::put('/cliente/actualizar', 'ClienteController@update');
    
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['Administrador']], function () {

        Route::get('/categoria', 'CategoriaController@index');
        Route::post('/categoria/registrar', 'CategoriaController@store');
        Route::put('/categoria/actualizar', 'CategoriaController@update');
        Route::put('/categoria/desactivar', 'CategoriaController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/categoria/activar', 'CategoriaController@activar');
        Route::get('/categoria/selectCategoria', 'CategoriaController@selectCategoria');
        
        Route::get('/producto', 'ProductoController@index');
        Route::post('/producto/registrar', 'ProductoController@store');
        Route::put('/producto/actualizar', 'ProductoController@update');
        Route::put('/producto/desactivar', 'ProductoController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/producto/activar', 'ProductoController@activar');
        
        Route::get('/proveedor', 'ProveedorController@index');
        Route::post('/proveedor/registrar', 'ProveedorController@store');
        Route::put('/proveedor/actualizar', 'ProveedorController@update');
        
        Route::get('/cliente', 'ClienteController@index');
        Route::post('/cliente/registrar', 'ClienteController@store');
        Route::put('/cliente/actualizar', 'ClienteController@update');
        
        Route::get('/rol', 'RolController@index');
        Route::get('/rol/selectRol', 'RolController@selectRol');
        
        Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
        Route::post('/user/registrar', 'UserController@store');
        Route::put('/user/actualizar', 'UserController@update');
        Route::put('/user/desactivar', 'UserController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/user/activar', 'UserController@activar');
   
    });
    
      
});




//Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Lo que cree 3 plantillas para los roles (Administrador, Vendedor, Comprador), en la ruta /resources/views/plantillas 3 archivos (sidebaradministrador.blade.php, sidebarvendedor.blade.php, y sidebarcomprador.blade.php); que esta los accesos para para rol

Para Administrador:

```html
<div class="sidebar">
            <nav class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li @click="menu=0" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="icon-speedometer"></i> Dashbord</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-title">
                        Menú
                    </li>

                   
                    <li @click="menu=1" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Categorías</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li @click="menu=2" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Productos</a>
                    </li>
                      
            
                    <li @click="menu=3" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Compras</a>
                    </li>

                    <li @click="menu=4" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Proveedores</a>
                    </li>
                       
                   
                    <li @click="menu=5" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i> Ventas</a>
                    </li>

                    <li @click="menu=6" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Clientes</a>
                    </li>
                        
                    
                    <li @click="menu=7" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Usuarios</a>
                    </li>

                    <li @click="menu=8" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Roles</a>
                    </li>
                        
                    
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <button class="sidebar-minimizer brand-minimizer" type="button"></button>
        </div>
```

Para comprador:

```html
<div class="sidebar">
            <nav class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li @click="menu=0" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="icon-speedometer"></i> Dashbord</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-title">
                        Menú
                    </li>

                   
                    <li @click="menu=1" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Categorías</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li @click="menu=2" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Productos</a>
                    </li>
                      
            
                    <li @click="menu=3" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Compras</a>
                    </li>

                    <li @click="menu=4" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Proveedores</a>
                    </li>
                       
                    
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <button class="sidebar-minimizer brand-minimizer" type="button"></button>
        </div>
```

Para Vendedor:

```html
<div class="sidebar">
            <nav class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li @click="menu=0" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="icon-speedometer"></i> Dashbord</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-title">
                        Menú
                    </li>

                   
                    <li @click="menu=1" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Categorías</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li @click="menu=2" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Productos</a>
                    </li>
                      
                   
                    <li @click="menu=5" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i> Ventas</a>
                    </li>

                    <li @click="menu=6" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Clientes</a>
                    </li>
                        
                    
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <button class="sidebar-minimizer brand-minimizer" type="button"></button>
        </div>
```

Dentro de la misma ruta /resources/views/contenido en el archivo contenido.blade.php se ha especificado una condiciona para cuando dependiendo del tipo de rol de usuario para a cargar en pantalla lo que debe de mostrar

```html
@extends('principal')
@section('contenido')

@if(Auth::check())
          @if (Auth::user()-idrol == 1) 
              <template v-if="menu==0">
              <h1>Escritorio</h1>
              </template>

              <template v-if="menu==1">
                <categoria></categoria>
              </template>

              <template v-if="menu==2">
                <producto></producto>
              </template>

              <template v-if="menu==3">
                <h1>Compras</h1>
              </template>

              <template v-if="menu==4">
                  <proveedor></proveedor>
              </template>

              <template v-if="menu==5">
                <h1>Ventas</h1>
              </template>

              <template v-if="menu==6">
                <cliente></cliente>
              </template>

              <template v-if="menu==7">
                <user></user>
              </template>

              <template v-if="menu==8">
                <rol></rol>
              </template>

             @include('plantilla.sidebaradministrador')
          @elseif (Auth::user()-idrol == 2)

                  <template v-if="menu==0">
                  <h1>Escritorio</h1>
                  </template>

                  <template v-if="menu==1">
                    <categoria></categoria>
                  </template>

                  <template v-if="menu==2">
                    <producto></producto>
                  </template>

                  <template v-if="menu==3">
                    <h1>Compras</h1>
                  </template>

                  <template v-if="menu==4">
                      <proveedor></proveedor>
                  </template>
                  <template v-if="menu==5">
                      <h1>Ventas</h1>
                  </template>

                  <template v-if="menu==6">
                       <cliente></cliente>
                  </template>
             @include('plantilla.sidevarvendedor')
          @elseif (Auth::user()-idrol == 3)

                  <template v-if="menu==0">
                     <h1>Escritorio</h1>
                  </template>

                  <template v-if="menu==1">
                    <categoria></categoria>
                  </template>

                  <template v-if="menu==2">
                    <producto></producto>
                  </template>

                  <template v-if="menu==3">
                    <h1>Compras</h1>
                  </template>

                  <template v-if="menu==4">
                      <proveedor></proveedor>
                  </template>

             @include('plantilla.sidebarcomprador')
          @else

          @endif
@endif
 
 


@endsection
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente ¿porque al ejecutar mi proyecto de laravel con php artisan serve y en una nueva pestaña del google chrome al ejecutar el proyecto me dice que no existe el controlador LoginController.php?; que bien en el archivo web.php que esta en /routes/web.php se han agrupado las rutas por grupos de roles Administrador, Comprador y Vendedor; si del archivo /resources/views/auth/login.blade.php en un formulario de ingreso de credenciales al hacer post llama con petición login al controlador LoginController.php; adjunto mi codigo del archivo login.blade.php

```html
@extends('auth.contenido')

@section('login')
<div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="card-group mb-0">
          <div class="card p-4">
          <form class="form-horizontal was-validated" method="POST" action="{{ route('login')}}">
           {{ csrf_field() }}
              <div class="card-body">
              <h3 class="text-center bg-success">Compras - Ventas</h3>
             
              <div class="form-group mb-3{{$errors->has('usuario' ? 'is-invalid' : '')}}">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" value="{{old('usuario')}}" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario">
                {!!$errors->first('usuario','<span class="invalid-feedback">:message</span>')!!}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group mb-4{{$errors->has('password' ? 'is-invalid' : '')}}">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                {!!$errors->first('password','<span class="invalid-feedback">:message</span>')!!}
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success px-4"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-2x"></i> Iniciar sesión</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

y adjunto pantalla del mensaje de error que dice LoginController.php no existe ¿como soluciono esto?

[![Middleware - Laravel . LoginController.php no existe][1]][1]

¿Como solucionó este inconveniente?

Comment: agregaste un montón de código y de imagenes las cuales no creo que sirvan de nada para el error que tienes, intenta eliminar esta pregunta y realizar otra que sea mas puntual. Creo que el error esta solo en tu LoginController

Comment: Prueba 2 cosas, la primera ver que efectivamente tienes el LoginController en `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` y la segunda ejecutar un `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Un par de cosas: en el archivo `contenido.blade.php` tenés mal escritos los if `Auth::user()-idrol == 1` te está faltando el `>` (`Auth::user()->idrol == 1`). Por otro lado, en otra pregunta mostraste tu archivo "LoginController", al que le habías borrado parte del contenido original, entre ello el `use AuthenticatesUsers;` y el `__construct()`. Por último, hacé un `php artisan route:list`, porque dudo que estén bien definidas las rutas. 3 middlewares con rutas repetidas. Ojo porque estás haciendo muchas cosas de manera inadecuada y te estás llenando de problemas evitables.

Comment: Estimado @ManuelRobles En la parte de arribe explique un poco más de error que me sale acerca del controlador LoginController.php que me dice que no existe que explique un poco mas la idel que en el archivo web.php explique un poco mas de como están agrupados las rutas de acuerdo a los roles.

Comment: Estimado @azeós para el uso de esto use la documentación del link o enlace https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware, si puedes me ayudas con esto

Comment: Hacé por favor un `php artisan route:list` y poné el resultado en la pregunta.

Comment: Estimado @azeós en lo que me dices en la pregunta en la parte de arriba esta agregado lo que me sale al usar el comando php artisan route:list, en la que capture la pantalla pero al ejecutar el proyecto poniendo nuevamente desde el terminal php artisan serve y en el navegador localhost/proyectolaravel/public me dice lo que ves en la parte de arriba pagina not found 404, ¿como soluciono esto?

Comment: Se ven solamente 6 rutas, por favor publicá el resultado completo. Y sumá el contenido del archivo `LoginController`.

Comment: Estimado @azeós en la pregunta en la parte de abajo esta capturada las pantallas de las listas de rutas que tiene mi proyecto que realice con el comando php artisan route:list, ahora también quisiera que me explique este error que me sale una pantalla que dice Page not found 404 ¿como solucionarlo?

Comment: Borra todo, solo pon lo referente a `LoginController` por ejemplo `la clase, el arbol de archivo` y porque complicarte haciendo tu `login` modificando las rutas `php artisan make:auth` `*hasta laravel 5.8` si usas `laravel 6`, vee ala documentacion, con la cual debes mantener las rutas `Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@home');`

Comment: No tenés ninguna ruta `/home`, por eso te tira 404. Y por favor no publiques las cosas como imágenes, es difícil de leer y algún día pueden dejar de funcionar. Poné el contenido del `LoginController`.

Comment: Estimado @manrriquemenesesyaranga ¡Buenas tardes!; soluciones en gran medida este problema lo que dice es en en el archivo web.php que esta en la carpeta /routes/web.php puse if (Auth::check()){

    
} else {

    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


} y en archivo home.blade.php lo deje de esta manera @extends('auth.login')

Comment: Sigues teniendo errores de sintaxis, revisa esta línea `Auth::user()-idrol == 1` cuando debe ser con el símbolo de mayor que y quedar así: `Auth::user()->idrol == 1`

Comment: Aparte de lo anterior yo te pregunto, tienes una respuesta de otro usuario indicando una posible solución, ¿ya la probaste, qué errores obtuviste?

Comment: Estimado @Aprendiz ya esta solucionado de lo de Controlador LoginController.php tenía un error de sintáxis en ciertas instrucciones pero que ya esta solucionado. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo de rutas web.php (/routes/web.php) validé si el usuario no está conectado llame a Auth::routes(); y luego al comando Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); quedando así el archivo de rutas web.php:

```html
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {
     
    Route::get('/','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
      
    Route::get('/main', function () {
        return view('contenido/contenido');
    })->name('main');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['Comprador']], function () {
         
        Route::get('/categoria', 'CategoriaController@index');
        Route::post('/categoria/registrar', 'CategoriaController@store');
        Route::put('/categoria/actualizar', 'CategoriaController@update');
        Route::put('/categoria/desactivar', 'CategoriaController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/categoria/activar', 'CategoriaController@activar');
        Route::get('/categoria/selectCategoria', 'CategoriaController@selectCategoria');
        
        Route::get('/producto', 'ProductoController@index');
        Route::post('/producto/registrar', 'ProductoController@store');
        Route::put('/producto/actualizar', 'ProductoController@update');
        Route::put('/producto/desactivar', 'ProductoController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/producto/activar', 'ProductoController@activar');
        
        Route::get('/proveedor', 'ProveedorController@index');
        Route::post('/proveedor/registrar', 'ProveedorController@store');
        Route::put('/proveedor/actualizar', 'ProveedorController@update');
        
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['Vendedor']], function () {

        Route::get('/categoria', 'CategoriaController@index');
        Route::post('/categoria/registrar', 'CategoriaController@store');
        Route::put('/categoria/actualizar', 'CategoriaController@update');
        Route::put('/categoria/desactivar', 'CategoriaController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/categoria/activar', 'CategoriaController@activar');
        Route::get('/categoria/selectCategoria', 'CategoriaController@selectCategoria');
        
        Route::get('/producto', 'ProductoController@index');
        Route::post('/producto/registrar', 'ProductoController@store');
        Route::put('/producto/actualizar', 'ProductoController@update');
        Route::put('/producto/desactivar', 'ProductoController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/producto/activar', 'ProductoController@activar');
        
        Route::get('/cliente', 'ClienteController@index');
        Route::post('/cliente/registrar', 'ClienteController@store');
        Route::put('/cliente/actualizar', 'ClienteController@update');
    
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['Administrador']], function () {

        Route::get('/categoria', 'CategoriaController@index');
        Route::post('/categoria/registrar', 'CategoriaController@store');
        Route::put('/categoria/actualizar', 'CategoriaController@update');
        Route::put('/categoria/desactivar', 'CategoriaController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/categoria/activar', 'CategoriaController@activar');
        Route::get('/categoria/selectCategoria', 'CategoriaController@selectCategoria');
        
        Route::get('/producto', 'ProductoController@index');
        Route::post('/producto/registrar', 'ProductoController@store');
        Route::put('/producto/actualizar', 'ProductoController@update');
        Route::put('/producto/desactivar', 'ProductoController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/producto/activar', 'ProductoController@activar');
        
        Route::get('/proveedor', 'ProveedorController@index');
        Route::post('/proveedor/registrar', 'ProveedorController@store');
        Route::put('/proveedor/actualizar', 'ProveedorController@update');
        
        Route::get('/cliente', 'ClienteController@index');
        Route::post('/cliente/registrar', 'ClienteController@store');
        Route::put('/cliente/actualizar', 'ClienteController@update');
        
        Route::get('/rol', 'RolController@index');
        Route::get('/rol/selectRol', 'RolController@selectRol');
        
        Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
        Route::post('/user/registrar', 'UserController@store');
        Route::put('/user/actualizar', 'UserController@update');
        Route::put('/user/desactivar', 'UserController@desactivar');
        Route::put('/user/activar', 'UserController@activar');
   
    });
    
      
  
});

if (Auth::check()){

    
} else {

    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


}
```

En mi proyecto de laravel tengo en la raíz del proyecto un archivo que se llama home.blade.php que el codigo que puse es el siguiente:

```html
@extends('auth.login')
```

Y de esta manera no aparece este error, pero mi pregunta es la siguiente ¿como hacer para cuando un usuario esta logoneado y salir de la sesión pueda cerrar la sesión?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está el problema

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {

    Route::get('/','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
});
```

Estas diciendo al sistema que solo usuarios `logueados` accedan a `login` y al `formulario(showLoginForm)` `guest es igual a auth`

tienes que sacarlos del middleware, puesto que recien te logueas, para eso las rutas `/` y `/login` tienen que estar libres de middleware

```
    Route::get('/','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
```

en cuando al `salir session` el mismo `Laravel lo gastiona` en caso de ser tu, tienes que `destruir **guest**` algo similar a esto

```
$request->session()->flush();
```

Comment: Estimado @manrrique meneses yaranga, ¡Buenas tardes!; o sea lo que tu dices que Route::get('/','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login'); tienen que estar fuera del middleware ('guest')